# ajax list avaliable users small bug in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I have this javascript/ jquery to list available users.

HTML:

```
<input name="username" type="text" size="16" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();"/>                                   
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
<img src="images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
<div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lookup(username) {
    if(username.length == 0) {
    // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("php/rpc.php", {queryString: ""+username+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#username').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
</script>
```

This gives a list of available usernames that you can type in.

example HTML:

```
<li onclick="fill('user1');">user1</li>
<li onclick="fill('user1');">user1</li>
```

But the fill function does not work. If I add `alert('test')` a popup shows up, so it works, but it does not fill out the input field `username`

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: also {queryString: ""+username+""} should be more like {queryString: '" + username + "'}

Comment: Shot in the dark, but could something be causing `blur` right after calling `fill()` the first time? This would call fill with no argument, blanking out the input. If you remove the `onblur` handler, does the problem persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main bug here is that the `name` attribute of an `input` element is not the same as an `id` attribute. Either

```
<input name="username" type="text" size="16" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();"/>
```

should be

```
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" size="16" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();"/>
```

or the jQuery selector referencing it should be `$("input[name='username']")`.

The other possible bug - and it really depends on how you're declaring the javascript - is whether the AJAX-loaded HTML can access the `fill` function. One easy way to fix this, though you may lose out somewhat in performance if you're loading a large number of list elements, is to assign the event handler in the callback function:

```
     $.post("php/rpc.php", {queryString: username}, function(data){
        if(data.length >0) {
            $('#suggestions').show();
            $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data)
                // find list elements and attach the event handler
                .find('li').click(function() {
                    // this removes the need to pass in any arguments:
                    // just use the text of the list element
                    var val = $(this).text();
                    $('#username').val(val);
                    // as @SLaks notes, better a function than a string here
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#suggestions').hide();
                    }, 200);
                });
        }
    });
```

This removes the need for two functions, and makes the HTML you load with AJAX simpler, since you can just load

```
<li>user1</li>
<li>user2</li>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/WNJnc/3/ for a full working example of this code.